Error getting native address of native library: task_vision_jni
13:46:28.612  E  Didn't find op for builtin opcode 'FULLY_CONNECTED' version '12'. An older version of this builtin might be supported. Are you using an old TFLite binary with a newer model?
13:46:28.612  E  Registration failed.
13:46:28.616  E  Error getting native address of native library: task_vision_jni (Ask Gemini)
                 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error occurred when initializing ImageClassifier: Didn't find op for builtin opcode 'FULLY_CONNECTED' version '12'. An older version of this builtin might be supported. Are you using an old TFLite binary with a newer model?
                 
                    at org.tensorflow.lite.task.vision.classifier.ImageClassifier.initJniWithModelFdAndOptions(Native Method)
                    at org.tensorflow.lite.task.vision.classifier.ImageClassifier.access$000(ImageClassifier.java:73)
                    at org.tensorflow.lite.task.vision.classifier.ImageClassifier$1.createHandle(ImageClassifier.java:142)
                    at org.tensorflow.lite.task.vision.classifier.ImageClassifier$1.createHandle(ImageClassifier.java:135)
                    at org.tensorflow.lite.task.core.TaskJniUtils$1.createHandle(TaskJniUtils.java:70)
                    at org.tensorflow.lite.task.core.TaskJniUtils.createHandleFromLibrary(TaskJniUtils.java:91)
                    at org.tensorflow.lite.task.core.TaskJniUtils.createHandleFromFdAndOptions(TaskJniUtils.java:66)
                    at org.tensorflow.lite.task.vision.classifier.ImageClassifier.createFromFileAndOptions(ImageClassifier.java:133)
                    at com.dicoding.submissiondicodingevent.helper.FruitClassifierHelper.setupFruitClassifier(FruitClassifierHelper.kt:39)
                    at com.dicoding.submissiondicodingevent.helper.FruitClassifierHelper.<init>(FruitClassifierHelper.kt:25)
                    at com.dicoding.submissiondicodingevent.helper.FruitClassifierHelper.<init>(FruitClassifierHelper.kt:15)
                    at com.dicoding.submissiondicodingevent.ui.camera.CameraFragment.onViewCreated(CameraFragment.kt:71)
                    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:3152)
                    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:608)
                    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:286)
                    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2211)
                    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2112)
                    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2049)
                    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:703)
                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8015)
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:555)
                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1091)
13:46:28.651  E  TFLite failed to load model with error: Error getting native address of native library: task_vision_jni

I tried to integrate the ML model that my team made but there was an error when I tried to do a classification test based on the image, in logcat an error appeared as follows
Is there something wrong with the model?

So, "Are you using an old TFLite binary with a newer model?" -- as the error message suggests?
